# How to generate two factor authentication key-store(.p12) to connect with remote server

Tags: openssl, certificate, key, keystore, generate

Follow the below steps to generate keystore(.p12).

### OpenSSL setup

1) Download OpenSSL

https://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl/files/openssl-1.0.2j-fips-x86_64/openssl-1.0.2j-fips-x86_64.zip/download

2) Unzip and set its path in system variable path.

Path : C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin

OPENSSL_CONF : C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg

3) Confirm the setup. in CMD write "openssl". OpenSSL should open without warning and error.

### KEYSTORE GENERATION

4) Now unzip the folder received from salesforce which contains 4 files with extensions(.slr, .cert,.key,.txt)

rename .cert and .keyfile to cert.pem and key.pem( make sure you are changing the extension to .pem)

5) Drop these two .pem files in bin folder of openssl, means, C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin

6) [Important] Now open the CMD with admin access, not using other users. otherwise you will get an error like "unable to write 'random state'"

7) Run the following command to generate keystore that we will use to connect with staging.

openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -certfile cert.pem -out keystorename.p12 -password pass:keystorepassword@123

8) Enter passphrase for key.pem: Enter the password you received in .txt file from salesforce.

9) Check "keystorename.p12" which would have been generated at location C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin.

### CONNECTING ECLIPSE TO STAGING

10) open eclipse, create server and do the configuration like that.

Server host should be with cert prefix. "cert.staging.XXX.XXXX.demandware.net".

Password will be keystorepassword@123

11) If everything goes fine you will be able to connect to staging successfully and also you will be able to upload your cartridges. you can go to web dev to confirm whether all your codes have been pushed to staging or not.

Hope it will help many developers to fix their issue related to connection with staging using 2-factor authentication.